# Table View data lags by one character when using search in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When I try searching to filter data in a table view, the view lags by one character. For example, if I type "dog", the table would display data for only "do", although the data in the model seems to get the correct data for the entire string of "dog". Therefore, there is a disconnect between the model and view, considering the model data being given back seems to be correct. This eventually causes fatal errors for index out range.

I have tried reloading the table data in multiple different places, but it doesn't seem to be helping. Any advice on how to get the table to display the correct data for the entire input string?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Add here what have you tried so that others can understand it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you implementing `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol?. Should work fine filtering when `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` is called and, immediately after, `reloadData`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have not implemented that protocol, but I am attempting to now: Unfortunately I am using a UISearchDisplayController, not a UISearchController, therefore I'm not sure its going to work. I have so far: `updateSearchResultsForSearchController([searchControllerShouldGoHere])`  and  `func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }` In addition to using UISearchResultsUpdating in the class delegates

Comment: Thank you, after deleting my old searching methods and reimplementing while using UISearchResultsUpdating, the problem is solved